# laptop will not boot after attempting upgrade to 13.10

Tags: boot, upgrade

I wanted to update my OS to the new 14.04 LTS. I was running 12.04 LTS before and followed the advice that upgrades should be done in steps. I first upgraded to 12.10, which seemed to work fine, and later to 13.10. This was all done through the Software Manager. After the last upgrade, I am no longer able to boot up my computer. The GNU GRUB menu opens up, but after selecting Ubuntu, it just stalls with a blank purple screen. If I select one of the other kernels, it also stalls after "Loading initial ramdisk...". I can't get into the Recovery Menu, either. I'm still rather new to Linux and may have possibly made the situation worse. Unfortunately, nothing has worked yet.

I tried reinstalling from a flash drive and on my first attempt, the wizard recognised a previous installation. Unfortunately, the wizard also didn't like how my partitions were set up (I didn't change anything) and gave an error before closing. Unfortunately, I didn't write the error down, but it was about the boot partition. On the next attempt and ever since, the installation wizard has stated that

> "This computer currently has no detected operating systems."

This is strange, because I could see the disk and even access my files when booting up from the USB. At this point, I decided to back up my important files using dropbox. Before losing all my files, I wanted to try the Boot-Repair tool, which also produced no results, and the files are no longer visible when booting from USB. The link to the Boot-Repair log is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/7457249/.

If I then proceed through to the "Something else" installation option, I can see that the partitions still exist. This is what they look like:

> /dev/sda
>      free space (size indicated 1MB)
>      /dev/sda1 efi (33MB of 98 MB used)
>      /dev/sda2 efi (352634MB of 746330MB used)
>      /dev/sda3 swap (3725MB, none used)
>      free space (0MB)

Is there any way I might be able to get my computer to work and preserve my files as well?

Comment: Have you considered backing up all files and then just installing from scratch? It might be better to start with a fresh OS. Note: I'm not an expert on UEFI, but I don't know if the linux filesystem is supposed to be EFI (opposed to ext4). I was under the impression that only the boot partition on a UEFI motherboard needed to be EFI.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as far as I can see, is that as naerwenya mentioned, you don't have an ext4 partition, you have *two* efi partitions. I just recently got a new laptop, and replaced Windows 8 with Ubuntu 14.04. 1 swap, 1 efi, 1 ext4. That's my setup, anyway, and I don't have any boot issues. Now, take it for what it's worth, I'm no expert, but I would change partition type of sda2 to ext4(/). Be advised, if no OS is detected, and you carry on with the installation as is, it will run a full install, potentially over-writing any files on the drive. My advice would be to make a backup of pertinent files, then run a clean install.